# Unity 2D: after-image from OLED screens in a high contrast situation

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, iphone-x

When I test my unity 2D game on my iPhone X, all background and sprite elements on the screen have a blue "halo" when moving my character. I have explored the issue with transparency on mobile, but the issue seems really strange. The blue halo appears only when the background is black. Anything brighter and it is absolutely fine. So I doubt it's a transparency issue given that it appears only when a dark background is present.

It is visible only on mobile, so taking a screenshot is useless.
If anyone wants to test do the following. Download or open the image attached here to full screen. Zoom in just a bit so the shapes are taking most of the screen. Start moving the image left and right. Slow and fast and you should see a blueish after-image around the edges. This should happen only on some OLED mobile screens.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever encounters this. The result I mentioned is an after-image effect from the OLED screen on the iPhone X. I haven't tested on other OLED devices, but I assume depending on the software it is possible other models can experience this. The levels of Black are incredible, but when you have a high contrast situation between light and dark, an after-image is created around the edges of the contrast zone.

How to fix this?

Simply do not use full black backgrounds or elements. Near black colors in a game situation is indistinguishable from a true black, 0, 0, 0 RGB, choice. This might be a common game design principle I am unaware of and I am the only person stupid enough to use 0,0,0 in the first place, but anyway, I hope if someone has the same issue to read this and fix it easily,